# Prove that every ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$ has the form $m\Bbb{Z}=\{mk, k\in \Bbb{Z}\}$

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains, monomial-ideals, binomial-ideals

Prove that every ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$ has the form $m\Bbb{Z}=\{mk, k\in \Bbb{Z}\}$

help me please, I really need that to do the homework

Comment: You’re new to MathStackExchange. You should learn to use MathJax for the typesetting of equations and give more context to your questions besides « it’s a homework »: what you have tried, the main difficulties etc. Now think about Euclidean division in $\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: Start by thinking about what happens with an ideal generated by two integers $m$ and $n$. This is related to the Diophantine equation $mx+ny=d$. For which values of $d$ does solutions exist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$ and let $m=\min\{i\in I;i\gt 0\}$. Consider $x\in I$. By the Euclidean division property of $\Bbb{Z}$, there exists $q\in\Bbb{Z}$, $r\in \Bbb{Z},0\leq r\lt i$ such that

$$x=iq+r$$

$i\in I$ implies $iq\in I$ and $x-iq=r\in I$. So $r=0$ otherwise we would have found an element $r$ of $I$ such that $0\lt r\lt i$ in contradiction with the definition of $i$.

So any element of $I$ can be written as $iq$ and so $I=i\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: thank you very much, I have read your comment above, I just started participating so there are many unknowns, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It is considered bad practice to post answers to questions where the asker didn't show any effort in answering their question, what they have tried, their thoughts on the problem, etc. Please refrain from answering such questions in future. Thanks

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes point taken. I first posted a comment reminding the best practices like typesetting and giving context to the questions. Under normal circumstances I would have refrained from answering. I just did  because I wanted to encourage a New User. By the way he acknowledged my comment in a comment of his. I will not repeat in the future.